# How much CPU / bandwidth should PostgreSQL logical replication be using?

Tags: database, postgresql

I setup logical replication with PostgreSQL 11, following the directions here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-logical-replication-with-postgresql-10-on-ubuntu-18-04

Everything worked great, and upon testing, changes were replicated.

However, a month later... changes do not appear to be replicating, and Postgres seems to be using a lot of CPU and bandwidth.

- Load average is ~2.5 on a 2vCPU/4GB DigitalOcean server.
- Bandwidth is ~1MB/s.
- There is basically zero activity on this server & database right now.

This raises some questions, like:

1. Is this normal for a non-active database with logical streaming replication to be using so many resources?
2. Any ideas on why replication seems to have stopped? (Changing records on the primary server doesn't not affect the replica anymore)
3. Are there some pro-tips for monitoring and viewing replication status?

The main Postgres server log is full of these kinds of messages:

```
2019-04-22 06:26:16.986 UTC [20371] replica_user@server_prod LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 0/1EC21198
2019-04-22 06:26:16.986 UTC [20371] replica_user@server_prod DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
2019-04-22 06:26:17.010 UTC [20372] replica_user@server_prod LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 0/1EC211D0
2019-04-22 06:26:17.010 UTC [20372] replica_user@server_prod DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
2019-04-22 06:26:17.055 UTC [20373] replica_user@server_prod LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 0/1EC21208
2019-04-22 06:26:17.055 UTC [20373] replica_user@server_prod DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
2019-04-22 06:26:17.078 UTC [20374] replica_user@server_prod LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 0/1EC21240
2019-04-22 06:26:17.078 UTC [20374] replica_user@server_prod DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
2019-04-22 06:26:17.114 UTC [20375] replica_user@server_prod LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 0/1EC21278
2019-04-22 06:26:17.114 UTC [20375] replica_user@server_prod DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
2019-04-22 06:26:17.154 UTC [20376] replica_user@server_prod LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 0/1EC212B0
2019-04-22 06:26:17.154 UTC [20376] replica_user@server_prod DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
2019-04-22 06:26:17.186 UTC [20377] replica_user@server_prod LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 0/1EC212E8
2019-04-22 06:26:17.186 UTC [20377] replica_user@server_prod DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
2019-04-22 06:26:17.229 UTC [20378] replica_user@server_prod LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 0/1EC21320
2019-04-22 06:26:17.229 UTC [20378] replica_user@server_prod DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
2019-04-22 06:26:17.235 UTC [20378] replica_user@server_prod LOG:  could not send data to client: Connection reset by peer
2019-04-22 06:26:17.235 UTC [20378] replica_user@server_prod STATEMENT:  COPY public.class_registrations TO STDOUT
2019-04-22 06:26:17.235 UTC [20378] replica_user@server_prod FATAL:  connection to client lost
2019-04-22 06:26:17.235 UTC [20378] replica_user@server_prod STATEMENT:  COPY public.class_registrations TO STDOUT
2019-04-22 06:26:17.259 UTC [20379] replica_user@server_prod LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 0/1EC21358
2019-04-22 06:26:17.259 UTC [20379] replica_user@server_prod DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
2019-04-22 06:26:21.327 UTC [20418] replica_user@server_prod LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 0/1EC21390
2019-04-22 06:26:21.327 UTC [20418] replica_user@server_prod DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
2019-04-22 06:26:21.341 UTC [20419] replica_user@server_prod LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 0/1EC213C8
2019-04-22 06:26:21.341 UTC [20419] replica_user@server_prod DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
```

And the replica server is full of these kinds of messages:

```
2019-04-21 06:26:07.619 UTC [2967] LOG:  logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "replica_subscription", table "messages" has started
2019-04-21 06:26:07.645 UTC [2966] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "account_locations_pkey"
2019-04-21 06:26:07.645 UTC [2966] DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
2019-04-21 06:26:07.645 UTC [2966] CONTEXT:  COPY account_locations, line 1
2019-04-21 06:26:07.648 UTC [16353] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 2966) exited with exit code 1
2019-04-21 06:26:07.652 UTC [2968] LOG:  logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "replica_subscription", table "user_photos" has started
2019-04-21 06:26:07.663 UTC [2967] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "messages_pkey"
2019-04-21 06:26:07.663 UTC [2967] DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
2019-04-21 06:26:07.663 UTC [2967] CONTEXT:  COPY messages, line 1
```

Here's the load average just in the last 6 hours (and you can see when I removed the subscriber on the replica server).

[image]

And here's bandwidth:

[image]

Here's also an `iftop` result of just ~10-15 seconds of monitoring:

[image]

Comment: Look into the PostgreSQL log file.

Comment: Good call -- it is indeed full of messages -- I added them to the question.

Comment: And the standby server?

Comment: Ah, bingo!  I guess it's a primary key issue from when I copied the initial database over as a starting point... the keys were not reset to the latest value.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the logs at the suggestion from Laurenz, it looks like my initial load of data did not have the sequences on the primary ids correct for all tables.  (Not sure how this happened)

To resolve the replication issue, I did the following:

1. Dropped the subscription from the replica server
2. Dropped all tables
3. Reloaded all tables - schema only (no data)
4. Created the subscription again

This caused all data to be synced and it everything is back to normal again.  I confirmed by updating data and seeing it update in the replica server.

The high CPU load and bandwidth appears to be when there's a replication error, Postgres just tries over and over as hard as it can.